# Antd submit only changed form item

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a antd Form. It has two form items. I only want to submit a form item if its initial value is changed. I have given my code below.

```
        <Form
            // form={form}
            name="basic"
            labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
            wrapperCol={{ span: 16 }}
            // style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}
            initialValues={{
                widgetUuid: widget.uuid,
                paymentMethod: getSelectedPaymentMethod(widget),
                paymentPackage: chargingArrGet(widget)
            }}
            onFinish={onFinishSelect}
            // onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
            autoComplete="off"
            layout='horizontal'
        ></Form>
```

This is my submit method.

```
  const onFinishSelect = (values: any) => {
    const tenantGroupId = (userDetails && userDetails.OwnedEnterprises[0]) ? userDetails.OwnedEnterprises[0].groupId : "";

    if (values.paymentMethod) {
        let req = {
            "paymentMethod": values.paymentMethod == 1 ? "AddToBill" : 9,
            "msisdn": activeMsisdn !== "" ? activeMsisdn : null,
            "invoiceNo": activeCard ? activeCard.invoiceNo : null
        }
        dispatch<any>(updatePaymentMethod(tenantGroupId, values.widgetUuid, req));
    }
    if (values.paymentPackage) {
        let packageReq = {
            "newRatePlans": [values.paymentPackage]
        }
        dispatch<any>(updateRatePlan(tenantGroupId, values.widgetUuid, packageReq));
    }
}
```

How to identify only the changed values.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the onValuesChange function provided by Ant Design's Form component. Here's how you can do it:

Initialize your form and set up the onValuesChange function:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Form } from 'antd';

const YourFormComponent = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  // Initialize the initial values state
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
    widgetUuid: widget.uuid,
    paymentMethod: getSelectedPaymentMethod(widget),
    paymentPackage: chargingArrGet(widget),
  });

  // Function to handle form values change
  const onValuesChange = (changedValues, allValues) => {
    // Compare the changed values with the initial values
    const changedFields = Object.keys(changedValues);
    const hasChanges = changedFields.some(field => allValues[field] !== initialValues[field]);

    // If there are changes, do the dispatch
    if (hasChanges) {
      //dispatch go here
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      name="basic"
      labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
      wrapperCol={{ span: 16 }}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onValuesChange={onValuesChange} // Use the onValuesChange function
      autoComplete="off"
      layout='horizontal'
    >
      {/* Form items go here */}
    </Form>
  );
};
```

In this code, we use the **onValuesChange** function to compare the changed values with the initial values. If there are changes, you can do the dispatch.